# Number of Cyclic Prefixes in OFDM

Tags: digital-communications, ofdm

For an L tap channel, we have to add L-1 cyclic prefix(CP) in the starting of N symbols in OFDM. My doubt is that what happens if we change the number of cyclic prefixes, say I take the CP>>L-1 and in another case I take CP << L-1.

Thank You!

Comment: Do you understand the purpose of the CP?

Comment: @MBaz Yes, it is used to prevent ISI.

Comment: Then, what causes ISI in the wideband channel, and how does the CP prevent it? Understanding that will lead you to understand what happens when the CP is too short or too long.

Comment: @MBaz My understanding is that CP and OFDM convert the Wideband channel into several smaller narrowband channel. By adding cyclic prefix, we are just adding the L-1 symbols in starting so that even if ISI occurs, we will not lose out on our information. So if the CP is too short then ISI will take place.

Comment: But I have little idea what will happen if CP is too large, I think it will be wastefulness of bandwidth and data rate, apart from that what is the effect on other OFDM symbols